# Finder slow or frozen while connecting HD (10.8.4 on SSD)

Tags: macos, finder

Since some days it occasionally takes Finder seconds to minutes to show up files in folders. Now and then iTunes and Mail freeze as well, just like core apps like Disc Copy. Quite unusable.
Possibly related:
• It seems the problems appears especially (or only) when opening/showing content in sym-linked folders on the HD in my discdrive.
• As well problems seem to have become more present and waiting times longer since I'm staying at friends with a complex network.
<strike>• Trim is not enabled (no idea why, perhaps after an update - the wiseguy-friend installed it together with the SSD).</strike> Trim is again active.

My system: MB 2.4Ghz 13" late 2008, 8GB RAM, 128GB SSD (OCZ-VERTEX4), 1TB HD (7200 HTS721010A9E630) in disc-drive with 10.8.4 (mountain-lion) installed.

Things I tried:
• restarted several times
• repaired permissions on SSD drive twice (2nd time no issues) (greyed out on 1Tb drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Problem solved' Hard drive failing, it appeared to create bad blocks, constantly, my tech-friend told me.
Fortunately, by diving into the terminal and copy by using `cp -Rnp (and source and destination)`, i still could save 99% of work i didn't TimeMachine the last 4 months.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Spotlight for the folders and or drive in question.
That should speed things up.

Or you can try to completely disable spotlight to see if that was the problem

Go to your Terminal and paste this

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
```

Once satisfied you can enable the spotlight

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
```